# Access linux guest on hyper v host

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I'm running an Ubuntu 20.04.1 guest VM on Windows 10 under Hyper-V. I wish to be able to access this machine by it's host name.

I am currently using the External Virtual Switch that uses the network DHCP to get it's IP.

I could use an entry in the hosts file to access this IP by name, but I cant make this IP static, and cant rely on it being the same each time I start the VM.

I have seen solutions to this that use Samba and the workgroup to do this. However my Host machine is part of a domain and not a workgroup and I have no access to the domain name server, so this isn't an option.

So my question is, is there any way to address the VM by name and not IP. So I could address a web server on the VM as http://guestvm/website rather than http://192.168.1.54/website.

Running under QEMU I was able to port forward to the guest so that I was then able to address SSH on the guest as http://127.0.0.1:2222 (with 2222 forwarded to 22) which is acceptable. (but QEMU is Slooooow)

I require the Guest to have access to the internet via the Host, and the host as well.

Thanks

Comment: "However my Host machine is part of a domain"  Once possibility is to (via your IT support) have a DHCP reservation for your host machine. Then you have a "static" IP and then you can use the HOSTS file concept. This will be the simplest approach if you can have a Reserved IP for your host machine.

Comment: I cant get a fixed IP, but I found a work-around using a Powershell script to find the IP of the VM and insert it as a name in the hosts file. Just run it whenever I start the VM.